# c# newbie lost in recursive function

Tags: c#

Hi I have problem with recursion in c#

Here is the code:

```
 static int g(int a)
 {
   if (a > 0) 
     return -2 * g(a - 2) + 2;
   else 
     return -2;
 }
```

What is the result for:

```
Console.WriteLine(g(5));
```

Could some one explain me what is the value of int g when is not declared like int a ?

Comment: "int g" is what data type the function "g" returns.

Comment: `What is the result` GEE, if only there were some way to find out......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could some one explain me what is the value of int g when is not
>   declared like int a ?

I don't understand what does the question mean, althought I'm going to explain you what does the function return if you pass 5.

Firstly lets declare another integer to make it easier:

```
static int g(int a)
{
   if (a > 0){
      int result = g(a - 2); 
      return -2 * result + 2;
   }
   else 
     return -2;
}
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine(g(5)) //-2*(-10)+2 = 22

if 5 > 0
  result = g(3) //-2*(6)+2 = -10
  return -2 * result + 2

if 3 > 0
  result = g(1) //result = -2*(-2)+2 = 6
  return -2 * result + 2

if 1 > 0
  result = g(-1) //result = -2
  return -2 * result + 2

if -1 < 0
  return -2
```

Answer (score -2):

You appear to lack an understanding of recursion. Let's simplify recursion to a "classic" base case which is much simpler than your example. Let's do a sum of from 1 to an input number:

```
public int SumAll(int number)
{
    // Base case
    if (number == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Recursive call
    return number + SumAll(number - 1);
}
```

Recursion always involves both calling a method within itself and a "base case" or termination step that stops the loop. In the above example, the "base case" is the number being equal to 1 to stop the loop.

The above example will evaluate as follows

```
return 5 + SumAll(4);
```

And SumAll(4) will evaluate as:

```
return 4 + SumAll(3);
```

Thus far, our final result will be:

```
5 + 4 + Sum(3);
```

And so forth... Study the method to understand why.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question that was asked.